# Ubutnu 9.10 samba after restart

Tags: ubuntu, samba, reboot

I have one drive that automatically mounts on boot, I have shared it and that works, but after restart the share no longer works, but the drive mounts. Ubuntu thinks it shared with the share icon showing, but in its network places it doesn't show and i cant see it on computers anymore.

UPDATE:It will work if i manually start it with sudo /etc/init.d/samba start

Comment: Please can you attach your smb.conf (or at least, globals and properties of relevant share) and the line in fstab with your mount command? Especially interested in the security= line in smb.conf (user? share?)

Answer (score 1):

This command should make samba start by default.

```
sudo update-rc.d samba defaults
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I just get a reply saying samba is allready there. And still doesnt work after restart

Comment: If the share works after "sudo /etc/init.d/samba start", then the problem is that samba wasn't running, and this answer should work. :S